# fgetcsv only read first line of csv-file (UPDATE: includes solution)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo, fgetcsv

i've the following code but it isn't working well. it only reads the first line of the csv-file, why? can anybody help me? i'm frustrated :(

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['prof_datei']['tmp_name'], "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $insert_profs_data = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO professoren (name, titel_prof, titel_dr, titel_ing) VALUES (:eins, :zwei, :drei, :vier)");
    $insert_profs_data->bindParam(':eins', $data[0]);
    $insert_profs_data->bindParam(':zwei', $data[1]);
    $insert_profs_data->bindParam(':drei', $data[2]);
    $insert_profs_data->bindParam(':vier', $data[3]);
    $insert_profs_data->execute();
}

fclose($handle);
```

UPDATE solution: If you're working with mac to execute this code, you should add the following code line before you open the file:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Comment: pls. add the first 10 lines from the CSV so that we can help you

Comment: Maybe because the file in `$_FILES['prof_datei']['tmp_name']` is a temporary file which will be deleted when this script is finished. Possibly something in the MySQL extension is giving PHP the idea the script is finished and PHP then deletes the file. Try moving it to a real file, processing it, and then deleting it.

Comment: A big note in the PHP docs for [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) reads: `Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.`

Comment: thank you! it works!!! :) :) i will edit my first code :)

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer based on Mark Baker's and johny's comments.

On Mac (OS X) and probably other operating systems that use different line endings, you may set `auto_detect_line_endings` to true, before reading the file.

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$contents = file('unknowntype.txt');
```

This should solve the issue of PHP reading only the first line of a file.